# An SKAction.moveBy is not working and i can't tell why

Tags: swift, xcode, gamekit

I've been following Jared Davidson's tutorial [How to make Flappy Bird](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjUvEiNxWfc) and I don't know why one of the functions that is using the SKAction.moveBy isn't working. I think part of the problem is that it might be in landscape mode. The user is supposed to touch the screen which causes the ghost to jump and the obstacles to start moving. Someone please help. Here is my code for the one function:

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    if (gameStarted == false)
    {
        gameStarted = true
        let spawn = SKAction.run(
        {
            () in

            self.createObstacles()
        })

        let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.0)
        let spawnDelay = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])
        let spawnDelayForever = SKAction.repeatForever(spawnDelay)
        self.run(spawnDelayForever)

        let distance = CGFloat(self.frame.width + 20)
        let moveObstacles = SKAction.moveBy(x: distance, y: 0, duration: TimeInterval( 0.01*distance))
        let removeObstacles = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        moveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([moveObstacles, removeObstacles])

        ghost.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        ghost.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 90))


    }
    else
    {
        ghost.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        ghost.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 90))
    }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't quite make sense because it doesn't say what the user touches.

Comment: @ElTomato Fixed it

Comment: You are not touching the ghost node in the touchesBegan method.

Comment: @ElTomato The problem is not that. The ghost itself is jumping but the pipes are not mocving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just recently ran into this same problem, and was able to solve it by moving the

```
    let wallDistance = CGFloat(self.frame.size.width + wallPair.frame.width)
    let moveWall = SKAction.moveBy(x:  -wallDistance, y: 0, duration: 
            TimeInterval(0.008 * wallDistance))
    let removeWall = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    moveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([moveWall, removeWall])
```

down under where you create top and bottom wall inside of createWalls. I put it under the setScales.

Then after that you add

```
    wallPair.run(moveAndRemove)
```

under where you add topWall and bottomWall as children.

Comment: Yea I figured it out today!!! I should've probably taken it down. But I'll leave it up for other people. Thanks a lot dude!!

Comment: I'll let you know if I have any more questions tho!

Comment: Did you figure out the rest of the tutorial?

Comment: Could you help me out with something?

Comment: Yea, whats up? Sorry for the super late response, i havent checked this in a while..

Comment: It's all g. I started on a new project